# Android TextView styles

Tags: android-layout, android, android-theme

I'm trying to set styles for TextView control. I am able to add either user defined style or system style. But I can't set both for my TextView. I want to display TextView like button style and I have to add width and height.
My Layout code is:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/trans_payable"
    <-- style="@android:style/Widget.Button" -->
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:paddingLeft="10sp"
    android:paddingTop="20sp"
    android:paddingRight="50sp"
    style="@style/transactionbtn"
    android:text="@string/trans_payable" >
</TextView>
```

And my style.xml code is:

```
<style name="transactionbtn">
    <item name="android:width">140dp</item>
    <item name="android:height">45dp</item>
    <-- How to add button style here -->
</style>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your style can inherit another style, e.g. a style from the Android resources.

```
    <style name="Button" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
        .
        .
        .
    </style>
```

Change the parent to `@android:style/Widget.Holo.Button` for Holo style.